# UnicodeDecodeError tells you position of character causing error. How can I display that character?

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, python-unicode

When opening/reading a file using something like

```
with open(<csv_file>) as f:
    df = pandas.read_csv(f)
```

it is possible to get an error such as

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 1678
```

I know I can use a vscode extension to locate the character in the csv_file at position 1678. But is there a way I can do it with python. Naively, something like.

```
>>getCharInPosition(1678)
"The character is that position is 'x'"
```

Or even better, getting the line number

```
>>getLineNumOfCharInPosition(1678)
"The line number for the character in that position is 25"
```

I'm looking for a way of making the standard UnicodeDecodeError message more useful than just telling me a character position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UnicodeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#UnicodeError) has quite a bit of information in its attributes.

By catching the exception, you can exploit this to find the offending bytes:

```
try:
    df = pandas.read_csv(f)
except UnicodeError as e:
    offending = e.object[e.start:e.end]
    print("This file isn't encoded with", e.encoding)
    print("Illegal bytes:", repr(offending))
    raise
```

In order to determine the line number, you can maybe do something like this (inside the except clause):

```
    seen_text = e.object[:e.start]
    line_no = seent_text.count(b'\n') + 1
```

... but I'm not sure if `e.object` is always a (byte) string (this could cause extra trouble for huge files), so I don't know if it always works.

Also, in a CSV file, the number of newlines might be greater than the number of logical rows, in case there are newlines inside some the cells.